# Convert mp3 to text on IIS web server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have a IIS website where users can upload mp3 files.  I would like to extract the speech from the mp3 file out to a text file.  I've successfully added the following IMPORT's:

```
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Speech" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Globalization" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Speech.Recognition" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Speech.Synthesis" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="Microsoft.Speech" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Speech.Recognition" %>
```

However, then the following command fails (VB.NET):

```
Dim sre1 As New SpeechRecognitionEngine
Dim sre2 As New SpeechRecognitionEngine(New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Error: Type 'SpeechRecognitionEngine' is not defined.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

Go to **Project** then **Add Reference...**, go to the **.NET** tab, find and double click on **System.Speech** (Or select it and press ok).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using Visual Studio - I'm writing code using just a text editor.

Comment: Wut? Then how do you get an error without debbuging?

Comment: Ok....but I don't think you can solve your problem with a text editor :)

Comment: You know that what Visual Studio produces is, ultimately, just text, right?  Even references are just text that point to a dll, library, etc.  You don't need VS to create .NET websites...it's just a tool to help.  You can do it easily on your own by saving a page with a .aspx ending and including the <%@ Page %> tag at the beginning of the page.